# Linux DNS resolution rejects certain names

Tags: linux, dns

I was playing around with wildcard domains (considering using them for a future project), when I noticed an odd discrepancy.

My domain is configured with a wildcard DNS entry (`*.vgoc.info`). I tried pinging `a_.vgoc.info`, and on Linux, I get

```
$ ping a_.vgoc.info
ping: unknown host a_.vgoc.info
```

But, on OS X, I get

```
$ ping a_.vgoc.info
PING vgoc.info (174.2.65.138): 56 data bytes
```

and similarly on Windows.

Does anyone know if Linux has some special "name validation" that rejects certain patterns? For example, `ping a_b.vgoc.info` and `ping a__b.vgoc.info` work fine, but `ping a-.vgoc.info` does not.

According to my reading of the DNS spec, such names are not illegal. Is there some other reference which restricts such names?

Comment: Not a programming question, therefore off-topic?  I think probably [su], or maybe [sf]

Comment: Originally I discovered the problem through `gethostbyname` and friends, and I'm positive the answer involves some Linux documentation or resolver code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because your domain names are not legal according to [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt). Each part of a domain name (between dots) is called a "label", and here is the grammar for a label:

```
<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]
<ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>
<let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"
<let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>
```

Notice that underscores are never legal, and that a label may not start or end with a hyphen.